# oauth 2.0 playground returns http 404 error with auth0?

Tags: oauth-2.0, auth0, oauth2-playground

I'm currently trying to go through the test suite for a smart home device I'm making, the instructions are here: https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/tools/smart-home-test-suite

The instructions tells me to get the "agentUserId", I need to use oauth2 playground, I put in the oauth2 information as required,
[image]

I left out the client ID and client secret out because of the screenshot.
I put the developers URL into auth0 permission list.
I put in 'devices' or 'email' as scopes but I always get the error below:

```
Something bad happened: 404 HTTP error. Message: <!doctype html> <html lan.........
```

it's returning a page not found. Thinking that something is wrong with auth0, I tried the same thing with openID playground but that works fine. What could be going on that is generating the page not found?

Answer (score 0):

turns out it was an issue with auth0. I just had to create another application and move all the fields over and it worked!